# Opencv SIFT feature extraction error

Tags: opencv, sift, surf

I met errors when I extracting SIFT feature for a large image. It is ok for smaller image.

Does anyone know how to solve it? Does the size of the image matter?

The size of the image is 2816 * 2122. The code I used is:

```
SiftFeatureDetector detector;    
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object;      
detector.detect(img, keypoints_object);  // Here I met errors.
```

The error is posted here:
http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14223529532113216.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think the increase of resolution will also increase the number of features detected by SIFT.
Why don't you resize the images so they become much smaller and then execute feature matching? So you have a fast solution for the homography which then can be applied or scaled back to the original size.
e.g.: http://answers.opencv.org/question/26173/the-relationship-between-homography-matrix-and-scaling-images/